Использование видеокарты вместо процессора в unity
Мой процессор не справляется с нагрузками, когда я запускаю тестовую игру в unity. При этом моя видеокарта совсем не загружается и почти не используется. Можно ли как-то сделать основную нагрузку на видеокарту вместо процессора, когда я работаю в unity

Это зависит от того, что собственно за нагрузка у вас

Между процессором и видеокартой, как не странно есть разница. Есть вариант, просто не загружать процессор бессмысленной нагрузкой.

andreymal, я запускаю сцену в юнити и процессор в диспечере загружается до 90-95%, когда видеокарта загружаетмя на 30-40

Вероятнее всего у вас просто отвал оптимизации, большое количество полигонов/логики и тд могут сильно нагрузить процессор, необходим баланс и оптимизация.

Если в сцене есть ландшафт - выключите и посмотрите на результат. Если стало значительно лучше - разбирайтесь, как можно это исправить. Если нет ландшафта или нет улучшения, то  разбирайтесь как использовать профилировщик Unity, и ищите, с его помощью, что конкретно грузит процессор.
